# More than 4000 chars gives string literal too long error on oracle

Tags: oracle

While updating a field that will have more than 4000 chars, I was given a error :

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

So, going through few blogs, I got this:

```
declare
    vClobVal varchar2(32767) := 'long text'
begin
    update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY = vClobVal 
    where FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID=240;
end;
```

This worked for me when fired at Toad.
Now, I created a stored procedure and compiled as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FMIS3.UPDATE_LETTER_BODY  ( 
    body_text IN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_LETTER_BODY%type,
    condition_id IN FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER.FKOL_OFFICEWISE_LETTER_ID%type
) IS
begin    
    update FMS_K_OFFICEWISE_LETTER set FKOL_LETTER_BODY = body_text 
end;
```

which is called as :

```
 call UPDATE_LETTER_BODY('long string',201);
```

and this does not work for more than 4000 chars again. Can't I define the size of varchar2 as it gave me error? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do we have to guess the datatypes of all your columns?

Comment: FKOL_LETTER_BODY has datatype CLOB

Comment: How are you passing the value to the procedure? Are you sure it's the procedure that's failing, rather than the way you're calling it?

Comment: Actually, its fine with string that is less than 4000 chars

Comment: Yes, but are you trying to pass more than 4000 chars as a string as the argument to the procedure call, or are you passing in a CLOB, or something else? Can you add the call to the question?

Comment: The string literal you're passing as an argument is still too long; your [`call`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4008.htm) is in an SQL context, not PL/SQL, so it's limited to 4000 rather than 32767 charecters.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the oci8 driver I am using doesn't support PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex Poole is correct, the call is in an SQL context which can only handle 4000 characters.  You could solve this by calling the method in a block like this:

```
Begin
   UPDATE_LETTER_BODY('long string',201);
End;
/
```

Other options include using another method to call Update_Letter_Body, creating a method to be called repeatedly to add text over 4000 characters, or using multiple input parameters.